# Kernel upgrade (4.10) made XServer and rest of the system fail (Arch)

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, x-server, watchdog, mesa

After 5 days not using my PC, I decided to get the latest packages which involved an upgraded kernel (4.9.11 -> 4.10.1), renamed and updated radeon graphics drivers (mesa) and some changes to KDE and Xorg.

Then things started to get messy after the upgrade. `startx` would not start the window manager but prompt me with a message saying 'Waiting for X server to begin accepting connections', during a reboot watchdog would halt the process and prompt 'watchdog0: watchdog did not stop' and every once in a while when I am logged in to the CLI a message pops up that says the following:

```
[*randomNumber*] INFO: task kworker/0:1:104 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[*randomNumber*] Not tainted 4.10.1-1-ARCH #1
[*randomNumber*] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message
```

(which it does not, I tried)

I tried reinstalling everything involving KDE, graphics drivers, xorg, etc. I even tried rolling back all packages on the system to March 1st but running `sudo pacman -Syyuu` to downgrade everything complains about broken package dependencies.

Configuring Arch and KDE to my liking was a pain and I would be very happy not having to reinstall the entire system.

Comment: Answers should go in the Answer box...

Comment: As @Jeff said, please post that as an answer to your question so readers can know this question has a solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it by downgrading again but this time I used `sudo pacman -Rcn ...` to force the removal of all packages that were said to have broken dependencies.